# Automatically share new updates on my website to social networks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, social-networking

Is there any way to update my social networks automatically from my own website admin panel?

Let's say I add a new article and I want to save it to my database and share it to my Facebook page and Twitter. Is there any code to do this? Has anyone made it before?

Comment: for you its rubbish but for me  it's very important dear.

Comment: this question is very serious Question , and I need an answer.

Comment: Just integrate with their APIs and post updates when appropriate.

Comment: Dear Sergey , is there any link for how to integrate there API to solve this issue ?

Comment: @Downvoters, considering the OP has 8 famous questions and [so] is the most popular resource for developers, please leave the downvoting and move along...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the following [CodeProject](http://www.CodeProject.com) article for full instructions:

**[C# Application Integration with Facebook & Twitter with oAuth](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380635/Csharp-Application-Integration-with-Facebook-Twitt)**

**Facebook:**

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(this.AccessToken);
string wallPost = "Your programmatic wall post using Facebook C# SDK";
dynamic result = fb.Post("me/feed", new { message = wallPost });
```

**Twitter:**

```
string tweetMessage = "Your programmatic Tweet using TweetSharp library" 
TwitterStatus twitterStatus = twitterService.SendTweet(tweetMessage);
```

**References:**

[Facebook Developer Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com)
[Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-)
[Twitter Developer Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/)
[TweetSharp Library](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharpcsharp-sdk)

---

<sub>I understand it's customary in StackOverflow answers to include a summary of the contents of a link or the highlights that specifically answer the question. And with a link-only answer, people must dig through another resource to locate an answer they might not be sure about and most importantly, if the link were to ever break, my answer is useless for anyone who visits this page in the future. However MSDN, Code Project, GitHub are generally acceptable links so I'm am not copying the entire article.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Check developer guides for [twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/) and [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com) on how to integrate them. There are also c# sdks for both platforms available on NuGet: [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) and [facebook](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Like already was said above have a look at the SDK's on the developers website(s)

or

Have a look at Twitterfeed.com, this website will allow you to provide a RSS feed with the latest (news,updates) and submits them automatically to Twitter, Facebook, linkedin etc

Simply generate an rss feed with your latest changes, provide it to twitterfeed.com and they do the rest